# Unable to loop array elements in an object

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

So I have a class in which I have a function to unzip an array of files. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
private function unzipFiles()
{
    $this->fileNames = array("file1.zip");
    $this->terminalPrint("Starting to unzip files...");
    foreach($this->filenames as $file)
    {
        $this->terminalPrint("Unzipping $file");
        ..... //other operations
    }
    $this->terminalPrint("Finished uzipping files...");
```

My problem is that when I call this function it prints `Starting to unzip files...` but never goes inside the loop to print `Unzipping file1.zip`. Neither does it exit abnormally or anything. It just conveniently skips the `foreach loop` and prints `Finished uzipping files...`

I tried giving multi-index array like `array("file1.zip","file2.zip","file3.zip");` but it just does not get inside the loop! Might be something really small, but I have been at it for so long that I thought maybe I might ask help from a fresh pair of eyes...

Thank you!!

Comment: try to change `$this->fileNames = array("file1.zip");` to `$fileNames = array("file1.zip");`

Comment: you should use an IDE for that stuff - most of them will even show your typo WHILE you type it. PHPStorm was pretty good with version 6 - dunno about the newer ones though ... i would assume even better.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo - `$this->fileNames` vs `$this->filenames`. PHP is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

The var with the name `$this->filenames` inside your loop is not declarated yet, you must replace this for `$this->fileNames`:

```
private function unzipFiles()
{
    $this->fileNames = array("file1.zip");
    $this->terminalPrint("Starting to unzip files...");
    foreach($this->fileNames as $file)
    {
        $this->terminalPrint("Unzipping $file");
        ..... //other operations
    }
    $this->terminalPrint("Finished uzipping files...");
```